# android sql where clause with id

Tags: android, sql, where-clause, clause

**Problem solved, look at comment below**

I'm trying to update a database, but the where clause doesn't work. I already looked at code samples, but they don't work for me.

This is how the table looks.

```
public static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES =
         "CREATE TABLE " + MessageEntry.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
        MessageEntry.COLUMN_NAME_ENTRY_ID + " INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY," +
         MessageEntry.COLUMN_NAME_ENTRY_USERNAME + 
         " VARCHAR(20)," +
         MessageEntry.COLUMN_NAME_ENTRY_MESSAGE+" VARCHAR(1000)," +
            MessageEntry.COLUMN_NAME_ENTRY_OUT + " SMALLINT NOT NULL DEFAULT  0,"+
         MessageEntry.COLUMN_NAME_ENTRY_STATUS + " VARCHAR(10),"+
            MessageEntry.COLUMN_NAME_ENTRY_TIME + " TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";
```

This is the method, that updates the table. There are a few update calls i tried, none of them works. Also tested with the hard value 1.

```
public void updateChatMessageStatus(long id,String status){
    MessageHelper helper = new MessageHelper(this.context);
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MessageEntry.COLUMN_NAME_ENTRY_STATUS, status);
    String[] where = {String.valueOf(id)};
    db.update(MessageEntry.TABLE_NAME, values, MessageEntry.COLUMN_NAME_ENTRY_ID+"=" +id, null);
    db.update(MessageEntry.TABLE_NAME, values, MessageEntry.COLUMN_NAME_ENTRY_ID+"=" +1, null);
    db.update(MessageEntry.TABLE_NAME, values, MessageEntry.COLUMN_NAME_ENTRY_ID+"=1", null);
    db.update(MessageEntry.TABLE_NAME, values, MessageEntry.COLUMN_NAME_ENTRY_ID+"=?", where);
    db.execSQL("UPDATE " + MessageEntry.TABLE_NAME+ " SET " +MessageEntry.COLUMN_NAME_ENTRY_STATUS+"='"+status
            +"' where "+ MessageEntry.COLUMN_NAME_ENTRY_ID +"="+1);
    db.execSQL("UPDATE " + MessageEntry.TABLE_NAME+ " SET " +MessageEntry.COLUMN_NAME_ENTRY_STATUS+"='"+status
            +"' where "+ MessageEntry.COLUMN_NAME_ENTRY_ID +"="+id);
}
```

I'm kinda stuck here, thanks for help.

Comment: Solved the problem. Instead of **auto_increment** I use **autoincrement** to create the id column. Now the update works fine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The id column was created wrong. Before I used **int** and **auto_increment** to create the autogenerated id column. But in android the right way to create a autogenerated key column is to use **autoincrement** and **integer**.

**corrected table**

```
   "CREATE TABLE " + MessageEntry.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
        MessageEntry.COLUMN_NAME_ENTRY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +...
```

**update call I use**

```
values.put(MessageEntry.COLUMN_NAME_ENTRY_STATUS, status);
    String[] where = {String.valueOf(id)};
    db.update(MessageEntry.TABLE_NAME, values, MessageEntry.COLUMN_NAME_ENTRY_ID+"=?", where);
```